# Given a function $~f:~$ find the intersection point of $Cf$ and $Cf^{-1}$

Tags: functions

I have several questions like this and the inverse of the given functions are too complex for me to use the classic $f(x) =f^{-1}(x)$ method.

Here is one:

$$f(x) =x^3 + x - 1$$
 What are the intersection points of $Cf$ and $Cf^{-1}$?

Comment: What do you mean by $Cf$?

Comment: I mean the graph of $f$. My math teacher uses it? Maybe it is not a worldwide thing.

Answer (score 0):

Points were `f(x)=f−1(x)` is truw is when x = f(x)

thus x = x^3 + x - 1

x^3 = 1

x = 1, there are complex solution too

And they are (-1+i*sqrt(3))/2

and (-1-i*sqrt(3))/2

Answer (score 0):

The graph of $y=f^{-1}(x)$ can be obtained by reflecting the graph of $y=f(x)$ over the line $y=x.$ Since both $f(x)$ and $f^{-1}(x)$ are continuous, increasing functions, this means that the graphs of $y=f(x)$ and $y=f^{-1}(x)$ will only intersect on the line $y=x.$ Thus, we must solve the equation $$x=f(x)=x^3+x-1,$$ or equivalently, $$x^3=1.$$ Assuming that we're only interested in real $x,$ we immediately have $x=1,$ and so $(1,1)$ is the unique point of intersection of the two graphs.

---

As an alternative, we can solve $f^{-1}(x)=f(x)$ by applying $f$ to both sides, yielding $$x=f\bigl(f(x)\bigr)=x^9+3x^7-3x^6+3x^5-6x^4+5x^3-3x^2+4x-3,$$ or equivalently, $$x^9+3x^7-3x^6+3x^5-6x^4+5x^3-3x^2+3x-3=0.$$ Graphing $y=x^9+3x^7-3x^6+3x^5-6x^4+5x^3-3x^2+3x-3$ readily shows us that $x=1$ is the only real solution.

---

As a further, more elementary alternative, we can start with the system of equations $$\begin{cases}y=x^3+x-1\\x=y^3+y-1,\end{cases}$$ since the second equation is equivalent to $y=f^{-1}(x).$ Subtracting the second equation from the first yields $$y-x=x^3-y^3+x-y=(x-y)\left(x^2+xy+y^2\right)+x-y=\left(x^2+xy+y^2+1\right)(x-y),$$ so since $y-x=-(x-y),$ we obtain the equivalent equation $$\left(x^2+xy+y^2+2\right)(x-y)=0.$$

As a result, we can conclude that $x^2+xy+y^2+2=0$ or $x-y=0$. In the latter case, we have $x=y,$ and can proceed as in the first approach. Completing the square ofr $x$ in the former equation gives $$x^2+xy+\frac14y^2-\frac14y^2+y^2+2=0\\\left(x+\frac12y\right)^2+\frac34y^2+2=0,$$ which is impossible, since the left-hand side greater than or equal to $2$ for all real $x$ and $y.$ Thus, $(1,1)$ is the only solution.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. It was quite simple to be honest, but I always seem to end up stuck on simple stuff like this one.

Answer (score 0):

The goal is to find all points $(x,y)\in\mathbb{R}^2$ such that the equations
\begin{align*}
y&=x^3+x-1&&(\text{eq}1)\\[4pt]
x&=y^3+y-1&&(\text{eq}2)\\[4pt]
\end{align*}
are both satisfied.

From $(\text{eq}1)-(\text{eq}2)$, we get
\begin{align*}
&y-x=(x^3-y^3)+(x-y)\\[4pt]
\implies\;&(x^3-y^3)+2(x-y)=0\\[4pt]
\implies\;&(x-y)(x^2+xy+y^2)+2(x-y)=0\\[4pt]
\implies\;&(x-y)(x^2+xy+y^2+2)=0\\[4pt]
\implies\;&x-y=0\;\;\;\,\text{or}\;\;\,x^2+xy+y^2+2=0\\[4pt]
\end{align*}
Consider two cases . . .

**Case $(1)$:**$\;x-y=0$.

Then $y=x$, hence $(\text{eq}1)$ reduces to $x=x^3+x-1$, or equivalently $x^3=1$, which yields $x=1$.

Thus, for case $(1)$, we get the point $(x,y)=(1,1)$.

**Case $(2)$:**$\;x^2+xy+y^2+2=0$.

\begin{align*}
\text{Then}\;&x^2+xy+y^2+2=0\\[4pt]
\implies\;&x^2+xy+y^2=-2\\[4pt]
\implies\;&4x^2+4xy+4y^2=-8\\[4pt]
\implies\;&(4x^2+4xy+y^2)+3y^2=-8\\[4pt]
\implies\;&(2x+y)^2+3y^2=-8\\[4pt]
\implies\;&(2x+y)^2+3y^2 < 0\\[4pt]
\end{align*}
contradiction.

Thus, for case $(2)$, there are no solutions.

It follows that the only intersection point is $(1,1)$.